# TypeError : Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I try to block some root if it's not an admin, but when I run the code I have a TypeError but I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks

roles.guards.ts

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Role } from './role.enums';
import { ROLES_KEY } from './roles.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return requiredRoles.some((Role) => user.roles?.includes(Role));
  }
}
```

articles.controllers.ts

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Roles(Role.Admin)
async addArticle(
    @Body('title') artTitle: string,
    @Body('description') artDescription: string,
    @Body('url') artUrl: string,
    @Body('cover') artCover: string,
    @Body('content') artContent: string,
    @Body('category') artCategory: string,
){
    const generatedId = await  this.articlesService.insertArticle(
        artTitle,
        artDescription,
        artUrl,
        artCover,
        artContent,
        artCategory
    );
    return { id: generatedId };
  }
```

when I run the code I have a TypeError but I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add more detail to [Jay McDoniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel) answer since it still took me a few hours to get around this issue.

1. Create `JWT.module.ts` (JwtModule is already used by @nestjs/jwt hence my use of caps) file with the following:

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { JwtModule } from "@nestjs/jwt";

@Module({
    imports: [
      {
        ...JwtModule.registerAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
              secretOrKeyProvider: () => (configService.get<string>("JWT_SECRET")),
              signOptions: {
                  expiresIn: 3600,
              },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
          }),
        global: true
      }
    ],
    exports: [JwtModule]
})
export class JWTModule {}
```

2. Add this class to your `app.module.ts`'s `imports` array.
3. if you have

```
{
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
},
```

in any of your modules... DELETE IT. declaring guards in any providers will automatically make it global and endpoints which you don't want to be guarded will end up getting guarded (I'm aware https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization#basic-rbac-implementation tells you to register the role guard in your providers but that just didn't work for me). You only need to import your strategies to the relevant routes.

4. In your controller, this should now work

```
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  @Roles(Role.Admin)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
```

so this endpoint accepts users with a valid JWT and an admin role inside said JWT.

Comment: Your post saved my day, so thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If I had to bet, your `RolesGuard` is bound to the global scope, whereas the `JwtAuthGuard` is bound to the route handler scope. Global guards execute first and foremost, so the `RolesGuard` executes before the `JwtAuthGaurd` can set `req.user` (passport is what does this under the hood). What you can do is either ensure that there is a `req.user` property (either via a middleware or jutt running the `JwtAuthGuard` globally) or you can move the `RolesGuard` to be scoped at the route handler level *after* the `JwtAuthGuard` runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use JwtGuard and RoleGuard in the controller like @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard). The issue because of RoleGuards is not used in guard.

```
@Roles(Role.ADMIN)
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard,RolesGuard)
@Query(() => [User], { name: 'User' })
```

articles.module.ts

in this module file update in provider rolesGuards

```
  providers: [AuthResolver, AuthService,LocalStrategy,JwtStrategy,RolesGuard],
```

Comment: this did it for me thanks, I just used @UseGuards(RolesGuard)

Answer (score -1):

use @Post() above your controller

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Roles(Role.Admin)
@Post('')
async addArticle(
    @Body('title') artTitle: string,
    @Body('description') artDescription: string,
    @Body('url') artUrl: string,
    @Body('cover') artCover: string,
    @Body('content') artContent: string,
    @Body('category') artCategory: string,
){
    const generatedId = await  this.articlesService.insertArticle(
        artTitle,
        artDescription,
        artUrl,
        artCover,
        artContent,
        artCategory
    );
    return { id: generatedId };
  }
```